# Error trying to use a shared module in Angular 9 make my components cant recognise my material module

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-directive

I have created a shared module to modularize my app so in case i want to use for example a Material component i can have it in other module by import it, the problem is when i do that give this kind of error `If 'mat-menu' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.` How can i solve it?.In the past without the shared module it worked perfectly but now no, and Its required to be with the shared module because its for homework

- Below i will let my three modules

***App Module***

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
//My imports
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { UsersDashboardComponent } from './components/users-dashboard/users-dashboard.component';
import { AdminDashboardComponent } from './components/admin-dashboard/admin-dashboard.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import { HomeAdminComponent } from './auth/home-admin/home-admin.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './auth/home/home.component';
import { CoreModule } from './../app/core/core.module';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    AdminDashboardComponent,
    UsersDashboardComponent,
    HomeAdminComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgbModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    RouterModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    CoreModule,  
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

***Auth Module***

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';
import { AuthRoutingModule } from './auth-routing.module';
import { HomeComponent } from 'src/app/auth/home/home.component';
import { HomeAdminComponent } from 'src/app/auth/home-admin/home-admin.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [HomeComponent,HomeAdminComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AuthRoutingModule,
    SharedModule,
  ],
})
export class AuthModule { }
```

***Shared module***

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MaterialModule } from 'src/app/shared/material/material.module';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MaterialModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  exports: [
    MaterialModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

Comment: Where are you using `mat-menu` in side Auth Module or App Module? 

Also, you can remove export in the shared module

Comment: Inside the `Auth Module` @prabhatojha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve it putting the `SharedModule` into the imports of the `AppModule`

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this problem you need to Add `SharedModule` as an import in all the `FeatureModules` where your components reside as declarations. Same like you have done in `AuthModule`. And also all the material modules imported into the `MaterialModule` should be exported in exports.

Comment: Additionally to Hari said, you also need to import the `SharedModule` into `AppModule`.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to create your own custom Components build on top whatever module you are using (in your case it is angular material) inside the shared module and then export these components and import your shared module in any other modules then, use these components, this will help you in the future if you decided to use another library instead of angular material or if you want to build some custom design.